# C# converting MimeMessage to .msg outlook

Tags: c#, email, mime, msg, mimekit

I try to convert a MimeMessage to a .msg with the `WriteTo` Method, but when I try to open the File I receive following error message:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Translated into english this means, that the file couldnt be opened, because the file is already opened or I dont have the permission to open the file. Neither of the assumptions is true.

I am sure that it has nothing to do with the MimeMessage I am calling the method with itself, because I was able to create a .msg from the same MimeMessage by using the `IndependentSoft.Msg` extension. (I cant use it anymore, since you have to buy a license after 60 days of using).

Its also interesting that the .msg that is produced by Independentsoft is twice as big as the one produced by MimeMessage (theres also no problem with the file saving procedure, since I use the same for Independentsoft and the new way)

Heres my conversion code:

```
public static byte[] ConvertMimeToMSG(MimeMessage mm)
        {
            if (mm == null) return null;
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var options = FormatOptions.Default.Clone();
                mm.WriteTo(options, memory);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Old Code with IndependentSoft

```
 public static async Task<byte[]> ConvertMimeToMSG(MimeMessage mm)
        {
            if (mm == null) return null;
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await mm.WriteToAsync(memory);
                byte[] byteArr = memory.ToArray();
                Independentsoft.Email.Mime.Message m = new Independentsoft.Email.Mime.Message(byteArr);
                Independentsoft.Msg.Message ma = new Independentsoft.Msg.Message(m);
                return ma.GetBytes();
            }
        }
```

Saving procedure:

```
                var fileAbsolutePath = Path.Combine(absolutePathToAkt, document.Ordner);
                
                if (!Directory.Exists(fileAbsolutePath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileAbsolutePath);
                var fileAbsoluteFilename = Path.Combine(fileAbsolutePath, document.Dateiname);

                File.WriteAllBytes(fileAbsoluteFilename, document.Buffer);
```

(the rest of the procedure would just confuse
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RnGn.png

Comment: Those aren't assumptions. The OS is refusing to open the file because it's already open. You need to find why that happens. Did you forget to close the FileStream you used to write the file? Did you forget to use a `using` block or call `.Close()` ? The code you posted doesn't store anything

Comment: as mentioned it has nothing todo with the storing procedure, because I also used the same procedure as it worked with independentsoft. Furthermore, in the meantime I have already restarted my PC and the fill still isnt openable

Comment: Can you open the file with an editor? Did you check Windows' Event Log? Is the file locked by an antivirus perhaps? PS: the code you posted doesn't write anything to `memory`. This code will return an empty array. There's no relevant code in this question and no useful information apart from the error message translation.

Comment: Try using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see what may have locked that file. From `Search` look for opened file handles using the file name

Comment: Sry I commented the wrong code. Additionally I added the old code. (it doesnt make a difference if I use WriteToAsync or WriteTo with the options)

Comment: I also added the code for storing the file. The search says that no process is using the file currently. I also copied the file to my laptop and tried to open it their, which didnt work as well

Comment: The file is  openable in an editor and looks normal

Comment: FWIW, MimeMessage.WriteTo(Stream) will save the message in MIME format, not MSG format. As far as the error goes, File.WriteAllBytes() opens and closes the file handle, so there's no hold on it there.

Comment: Just to be clear: MimeKit doesn't support the MSG format at all. Unfortunately, I don't know of any free libraries that support writing it (only reading it).